# Rails 4: Heroku push rejected / Gemfile Issues / GIT Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am truly confused and your help and explanation will be much much appreciated.

1.] my gemfile currently is displayed as below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.10'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
# gem 'foundation-rails', '5.4.5'
gem 'foundation-rails', '5.3.1.0'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'devise'
gem "ransack", github: "activerecord-hackery/ransack", branch: "rails-4.1"
gem "polyamorous", :github => "activerecord-hackery/polyamorous"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem "cocoon"
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'foundation-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'stripe'
gem "stripe_event"
gem 'cloudinary'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'mailcatcher'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'unicorn',        '4.8.3'
end
```

2.] my gemlock file is currently displayed as below:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.10)
      actionpack (= 4.1.10)
      actionview (= 4.1.10)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.10)
      actionview (= 4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.10)
      activemodel (= 4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.10)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts_as_commentable (4.0.2)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.3.pre1)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (3.4.0)
      columnize (~> 0.8)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2)
      slop (~> 3.6)
    cancancan (1.13.1)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    cloudinary (1.2.0)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    cocoon (1.2.6)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    devise (3.5.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20160615)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.5)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    font-awesome-rails (4.4.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    foundation-datetimepicker-rails (0.2.1)
    foundation-rails (5.3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)
    geocoder (1.2.11)
    guard (2.13.0)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, <= 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-minitest (2.3.1)
      guard (~> 2.0)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      turbolinks
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    kgio (2.10.0)
    listen (3.0.3)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mailcatcher (0.6.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0, <= 1.0.5)
      mail (~> 2.3)
      sinatra (~> 1.2)
      skinny (~> 0.2.3)
      sqlite3 (~> 1.3)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.99.2)
    mini_backtrace (0.1.3)
      minitest (> 1.2.0)
      rails (>= 2.3.3)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    minitest-reporters (1.0.5)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    nenv (0.2.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    notiffany (0.0.8)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    public_activity (1.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.10)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.10)
      actionpack (= 4.1.10)
      actionview (= 4.1.10)
      activemodel (= 4.1.10)
      activerecord (= 4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.1.10)
      actionpack (= 4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.15.0)
    rake (11.1.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.6)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    rmagick (2.15.4)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    simple_form (3.1.1)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    skinny (0.2.3)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    slop (3.6.0)
    social-share-button (0.1.8)
      coffee-rails
      sass-rails
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.9)
    stripe (1.46.0)
      rest-client (~> 1.4)
    stripe_event (1.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      stripe (~> 1.6)
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    twilio-ruby (4.5.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
    unicorn (4.8.3)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      rack
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (= 0.7.3.pre1)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts_as_commentable
  awesome_print
  bcrypt (= 3.1.7)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  byebug (= 3.4.0)
  cancancan (~> 1.10)
  carrierwave
  cloudinary
  cocoon
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  devise
  font-awesome-rails
  foundation-datetimepicker-rails
  foundation-rails (= 5.3.1.0)
  geocoder
  guard-minitest (= 2.3.1)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-turbolinks
  jquery-ui-rails
  mailcatcher
  mini_backtrace (= 0.1.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.0.5)
  pg (= 0.17.1)
  polyamorous!
  pry
  public_activity
  quiet_assets
  rails (= 4.1.10)
  rails_12factor
  ransack!
  rmagick
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  simple_form
  social-share-button
  spring (= 1.1.3)
  sqlite3 (= 1.3.9)
  stripe
  stripe_event
  turbolinks
  twilio-ruby
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  unicorn (= 4.8.3)
  web-console (= 2.0.0.beta3)
```

3.] when ever i run `bundle install` some additional info gets added to my gemfile called GIT - i believe this is what is causing heroku not to accept deployment of my app

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous.git
  revision: 8f722a1edfaf20dbb14b21e422c629249a6fbfa6
  specs:
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git
  revision: 742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b
  branch: rails-4.1
  specs:
    ransack (1.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.10)
      actionpack (= 4.1.10)
      actionview (= 4.1.10)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.10)
      actionview (= 4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.10)
      activesupport (= 4.1.10)
etc............
```

4.] when i do git push heroku master i get the below error message:

```
Counting objects: 3218, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3089/3089), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3218/3218), 175.45 MiB | 602.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3218 (delta 787), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * source: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous.git (at master)
remote:        * source: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git (at rails-4.1)
remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        
remote:        You have added to the Gemfile:
remote:        * source: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous.git (at master)
remote:        * source: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git (at rails-4.1)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my-app-name.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-app-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app-name.git'
```

> could one kindly tell me exactly how to resolve this as i have no
>   clue. i apologise if it is a basic question, but your help would be
>   much much appreciated - could you also advise me how i over-ride or update the `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 1):

Your gemfile is not up-to-date. Make sure you bundle install and then commit it to github, so all the changes are made to the source code, Now you can push to heroku.

1. On your local machine `cd` in the app directory and run `bundle install`
2. Now commit your changes to github `git push origin master`
3. Now push it to heroku `git push heroku master`

Comment: my app is not on guthub. when i run bundle install i get this GIT message in the Gemlock file `GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/polyamorous.git
  revision: 8f722a1edfaf20dbb14b21e422c629249a6fbfa6
  specs:
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git
  revision: 742425ade4bb66db573dc13bf436a8f3c87b733b
  branch: rails-4.1
  specs:
    ransack (1.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.1)`

Comment: how do i over-ride or update the 'Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: To update the Gemfile.lock you need to run bundle update.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues this is how I solved this.
 1. Run bundle install
 2. Commit Gemfile.lock and push to git
after pushing to heroku its working for me.